# How remove duplicate in select php foreach results

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am new to php and working on a project. I am facing a problem here.

```
<?PHP
$db_handle = new DBController();
$query ="SELECT * FROM agent";
$results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
?>
<script>
function getState(val) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "get_state.php",
data:'country_firstname='+val,
success: function(data){
$("#state-list").html(data);
}
});
}
function selectCountry(val) {
$("#search-box").val(val);
$("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
</script>
<div class="row">
<label>Country:</label><br/>
<select name="country" id="country-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getState(this.value);">
<option value="">Select Country</option>
<?php
foreach ($results as $country) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $country["firstname"]; ?>">Kannur</option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>State:</label><br/>
<select name="state" id="state-list" class="demoInputBox">
<option value="">Select State</option>
</select>
</div>
```

get_state.php

```
<?php
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_POST["country_firstname"])) {
$query ="SELECT firstname FROM agent WHERE firstname = '" .     $_POST["country_firstname"] . "'";
$results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
?>
<option value="">Select State</option>
<?php
foreach($results as $state) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $state["id_user"]; ?>"><?php echo $state["firstname"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Here I am facing the problem is the country name is repeating according to the values in DB. See the example http://moonamvazhi.com/db/agent1/sub.php

If i want the second value in state, want to select the second value of country.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using SELECT DISTINCT. This will only return unique results.

Comment: Not working!!!!

Comment: That's really not a helpful comment. Also the exclamation marks are a bit much mate.... You need to understand that helping you from the code you dumped is pretty hard (it's not even indented). Hence the few reaction you have on your question.

Could you try adding GROUP BY firstname at the end of your query?

Comment: Like: `"SELECT firstname FROM agent WHERE firstname = '" .     $_POST["country_firstname"] . "' GROUP BY firstname"`

Comment: Sorry.... I am not meant like that by exclamation.....sorry....I tried this....not getting

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array_unique` function to remove duplicate values in a array.
For more information visit this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php